# How to compare wheter a value exists in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of our SQL jobs and I want to create a unit test, that would evaluate whether a given parameter (job name) exists within the jobs.

I've tried:

```
-- Test function
     DECLARE @FinalResult NVARCHAR(30)
     DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (name VARCHAR(30))

     INSERT INTO @ResultTable
     SELECT [name] 
     FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
     WHERE [name] = @Parameter_Name
     -- Evaluation
     SET @FinalResult = SELECT TOP 1 FROM @ResultTable
     SELECT @TestResult = IIF(FinalResult IS NULL,0,1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just SELECT count(*)
     FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
     WHERE [name] = @Parameter_Name

Comment: @P.Salmon That would be better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`EXISTS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeWhere WHERE SomeCondition) --The '1' is of no importance... Just checking for any result...
BEGIN
    Do what ever you need
END
```

You can add an `ELSE` block to react to the opposite too.

Hint: You can negate this easily using `IF NOT EXISTS()`...

Answer (score 0):

A much simple way would be something like

```
Declare @JobExists INT
    ,   @Parameter_Name SYSNAME = 'Backup Job';

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = @Parameter_Name)
    BEGIN
      SET @JobExists =1;
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
      SET @JobExists =0;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
    DECLARE @Parameter_Name Varchar(MAX) = '' -- Job name
    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (name VARCHAR(30),JobExists bit )

    IF EXISTS( SELECT [name]  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = @Parameter_Name) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ResultTable (name, JobExists )
        Values (@Parameter_Name,1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ResultTable (name, JobExists )
        Values (@Parameter_Name,0)
    END
```